# Draw a bitmap in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

I am trying to draw some string to bitmap at certain position and copy a barcode bitmap to the new bitmap.I have not done with graphics before so i don't know where to start.

Can anyone guide me on this?my output of the bitmap is a receipt like.

Comment: Hi, please check the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. Please make a grid or canvas and put the barcode image and use a label with desired text and put the label on desired location relative to barcode grid. So, trick is you can immediately take screenshot of this grid  using following code.Then, you are done.

```
public void ConvertToBitmapSource(UIElement element)
{
    var target = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)element.RenderSize.Width, (int)element.RenderSize.Height,
        96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    target.Render(element);

    var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    var outputFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(target);
    encoder.Frames.Add(outputFrame);

    using (var file = File.OpenWrite("TestImage.png"))
    {
        encoder.Save(file);
    }
}
```